# MVC Form Required base on select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC form that has a required option for the City control but in JQuery I have it hide/show base on the Country dropdown. So if the Country is US the City control will display and the user will need to enter the city. The problem I am running into is that the form will only post if the city is enter. Is there around this?

```
[Required]
public string City { get; set; }
```

Comment: Using Jquery assign City="hidden".  In your controller check City. If (City="hidden") City=string.Empty

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The controller will not be hit because it’s required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go through the below article to get some idea for requiredIf Data annotation

https://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I have an idea from the article but I am changing the condition in jquery so I am not sure how to removing the fields.